# How to populate a dropdown menu in ahtml form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to populate a dropdown field inside a html form, but the field doesn't show any value, only a blank one.

I'm trying the following code:

```
<select name="Select" class="textfields" id="prods">
    <option id="0">--Producto--</option>

<?php
require("conectdb.php");
$allproducts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Productos");
while ($viewallproducts = mysql_fetch_array($allproducts)){
?>
    <option id="<?php echo $viewallproducts["ID"];?>"><?php echo $viewallproducts["CODIGO"];?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>
```

I have changed the quotes and ;... But still nothing, here is the code of connection to the Database (conectdb.php):

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno();

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It seems to be a problem of the database connection, Im trying now the following code to see what happens:

```
    <?php
 $username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$hostname = "xxxx"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


    $allproducts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS");
    while ($viewallproducts = mysql_fetch_array($allproducts)){
        echo ($viewallproducts);
    }
        ?>
```

But, on this php, I receive the following error:

> Warning: mysql:fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

I have also tried with mysql_fetch_row() and gives me the same error.

Comment: You never gave the options any values. Look at your output html code. Probably going to show that it's not valid.

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $viewallproducts['ID'];?>">

Comment: `require(conectdb.php)` string without quotes, and no `;`, should give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have error in require line(put file name inside quotation )
2) you don't put value attribute in option.

**Try  this:**

```
 <select name="Select" class="textfields" id="prods">
        <option id="0" value="o">--Producto--</option>

        <?php
        require("conectdb.php");
    $allproducts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Productos");
    while ($viewallproducts = mysql_fetch_array($allproducts)){
        ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $viewallproducts['ID'];?>" value="<?php echo $viewallproducts['ID'];?>"><?php echo $viewallproducts['DESCRIPCION'];?></option>

    <?php } ?>

    </select>
```

Comment: Not at the moment...  Maybe I have to change something in the Class pf the Select statement?

Comment: can you give me sample output html that you got from above code?

Comment: It shows only the field with the first line pointing to --Producto-- and there is a second line, that should have the information from the database, but shows nothing.

Comment: @Jesua: can you  `print_r($viewallproducts);` inside your while loop and check what you have got in it?

Comment: I have added some info above, trying an standalone php to see what happens, it seemed to be an issue with the database connection, but after making some changes, the problems goes to the php code...

Answer (score 0):

Some edit on your code:

```
<select name="Select" class="textfields" id="prods">
<option id="0">--Producto--</option>

<?
require("conectdb.php");
$allproducts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Productos")
or die(mysql_error());
while ($viewallproducts = mysql_fetch_assoc($allproducts)){
?>
    <option id="<?=$viewallproducts['ID'];?>" value="<?=$viewallproducts['ID'];?>">
    <?=$viewallproducts['DESCRIPTION'];?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>
```

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. You should also check if the sql query succeed first.

Comment: Note: short open tags are off by default on most servers, you should not use it

Comment: That depends. Different servers have different settings, and mine does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake because you think ID in html is ID in database. You need to use "value" attribute for option

chance this line

```
<option id="<?php echo $viewallproducts['ID'];?>"><?php echo $viewallproducts['DESCRIPCION'];?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $viewallproducts['ID'];?>"><?php echo $viewallproducts['DESCRIPCION'];?></option>
```

You have also forget about:

1. require argument in ''
2. ; after require
3. Function to get rows should be 'mysql_fetch_row' instead of 'mysql_fetch_array'

I would also suggest you using better DB engine for example **PDO** or **MySQLi** because **MySQL_*** functions are depracated.

Code formatted:

```
<select name="Select" class="textfields" id="prods">
<option value="0">--Producto--</option>
<?php
    require('conectdb.php'); // be sure that file exist you forgot about '' and ;
    $allproducts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Productos`");
    while ($viewallproducts = mysql_fetch_row($allproducts))
     echo '<option value="'.$viewallproducts['ID'].'">'.$viewallproducts['DESCRIPCION'].'</option>';
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to put the semicolon after the line

```
require(conectdb.php)
```

And you should add a quotation

```
require("conectdb.php");
```

Maybe is that